# Recommended method to call azure function Webhook

Tags: c#, azure, webhooks, azure-functions

I'm using the following code to call/trigger an Azure Function Webhook

I know know MS has a bunch of Webhook libraries although I'm unable to find a example of calling an Azure Function Webhook.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient()) {
                    var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Name = "Bob", Age = 30 }), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    var response = await client.PostAsync("https://url_to_webhook", content);
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
                        // do what needs to be done
                    }
                }
```

I thought MS might have had some code that looks more like

```
var webhook = new Webhook(url);
        var resultObject = await webhook.PostAsync<JObject>(new {Name = "Bob", Age = 30});
```

I know my code works just wanted to know if there is specific / optimized Webhook code...

I'm using .net core

Answer (score 2):

Webhook is effectively just HTTP endpoint accepting JSON in POST. There's nothing special about calling it or anything to "optimize".

If you want, you may use existing [`PostAsJsonAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclientextensions.postasjsonasync.aspx#M:System.Net.Http.HttpClientExtensions.PostAsJsonAsync<code>1%28System.Net.Http.HttpClient,System.String,</code>0%29) extension method (or implement it yourself, if it's not in .NET Core yet).